# Java / Android - JSON Parsing to Create New Multi-Message Chat Only Results in One Message

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm attempting to parse a JSON Array into multiple messages - however in my current implementation each subsequent message in my Array overwrites the value of msg instead of creating a new message for each message value in the array. I understand I'll need to create a new message inside my for loop - but I can't seem to figure out how to do so programmatically.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

### JSON:

```
{"messages":[{"message":"User has joined.","type":"agent","created":"2016-11-26 12:56:02","name":"Test User"},{"message":"Hello World?","type":"agent","created":"2016-11-26 12:56:05","name":"Test User"}]}
```

### JAVA:

```
private void populateMessages(JSONObject msgObj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < msgObj.length(); i++) {
        messages = ChatMessage.fromJson(msgObj);
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(messages);
        mListView.invalidateViews();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}



public static ChatMessage fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    ChatMessage msg = new ChatMessage();
    try {
        JSONArray items = jsonObject.getJSONArray("messages");
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = items.getJSONObject(i);
            if(json_data.getString("message") != null)
            msg.message = json_data.getString("message");
            if(json_data.getString("type") != null)
            msg.type = json_data.getString("type");
            if(json_data.getString("name") != null)
            msg.name = json_data.getString("name");

            if(msg.message.equals("Waiting for user.")){
                if(json_data.getString("created") != null)
                msg.created = convertInitalTime(json_data.getString("created"));
            }
            else{
                if(json_data.getString("created") != null)
                msg.created = convertTime(json_data.getString("created"));
            }

        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Gson would help you with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   private void populateMessages(JSONObject msgObj) {
        messages = ChatMessage.fromJson(msgObj);
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(messages);
        mListView.invalidateViews();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();        
   }


public static ArrayList<ChatMessage> fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {
  ArrayList<ChatMessage> messages = new ArrayList<>();
  try {
    JSONArray items = jsonObject.getJSONArray("messages");
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
       ChatMessage msg = new ChatMessage();
       ....
       ....
       messages.add(msg);
    }
  }

 return messages;
}
```

Move your new object in `for loop` and use `ArrayList`

Remove for loop in `populteMessage`

And in java prefer setter and getters

Thats all..